# How to make Login using facebook to trigger manually

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is the Login using facebook. I took the example for official docs.

Here the facebook login is checked automatically whenever the page is loaded. But i want to check it only on the button click.

So , i created a div with id

and had this one

`<div id="fblogin">click me</div>`

which triggers

```
$("#fblogin").click(function()
{
        console.log('fb initiated');
        statusChangeCallback(response);
});
```

Here as i don't know the value for `response` to call i am getting error `Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined`

Short  : I want to do trigger everything only if i click on button not automatically.

Here is my code that i have so far

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js">
</script>
<div id="fblogin">
  click me</div>
<script>
$("#fblogin").click(function()
{
        console.log('fb initiated');
        statusChangeCallback(response);

});
</script>
<script>
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'myappid',
    cookie     : true, 
    xfbml      : true, 
    version    : 'v2.2'
  }); 
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
  };
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
<div id="status">
</div>
```

**What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this ?**

Comment: I suggest that you remove `html` tag and add `javascript`. People who look for questions under `javascript` are much more capable of answering this.

Comment: this may help you: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove/Comment the call to `FB.getLoginStatus()` in `window.fbAsyncInit`. Then change your button's click event handler code to :

```
$("#fblogin").click(function()
{
    console.log('fb initiated');
    checkLoginState();

});
```

`response` is something that is passed to the callback function for `FB.getLoginStatus`, which requests and returns back in the response the login status of the user.

Comment: But it gives me `statusChangeCallback
fb.php (line 15)
Object { status="unknown",  authResponse=undefined}` error

Comment: Is it really an error ? As per the doc in here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus, response with `status="unknown"` means the user is not logged into Facebook.

Comment: So, can you tell me how can i deal with this

Comment: Since the status means the user isn't logged in, you will have to initiate a login dialog. You can do this by using `FB.Login()`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.3. Usually it's initiated on a button click.